# Spring cloud gateway with swagger 3 openapi doesn't work

Tags: swagger-ui, spring-cloud-gateway

Please help, I tried to configure the security permissionAll endpoint but it still doesn't work:

> Swagger config

```
@Bean
    @Lazy(false)
    public List<GroupedOpenApi> apis(SwaggerUiConfigParameters swaggerUiConfigParameters, RouteDefinitionLocator locator) {
        List<GroupedOpenApi> groups = new ArrayList<>();
        List<RouteDefinition> definitions = locator.getRouteDefinitions().collectList().block();
        for (RouteDefinition definition : definitions) {
            System.out.println("id: " + definition.getId()+ "  "+definition.getUri().toString());
        }
        definitions.stream().filter(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId().matches(".*-service")).forEach(routeDefinition -> {
            String name = routeDefinition.getId().replaceAll("-service", "");
            swaggerUiConfigParameters.addGroup(name);
            GroupedOpenApi.builder().pathsToMatch("/" + name + "/**").group(name).build();
        });
        return groups;
    }
```

> gateway application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: system-service
          uri: lb://system-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/system/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/system/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}
        - id: openapi
          uri: http://localhost:${server.port}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}/v3/api-docs
```

> WebFluxSecurityConfig

```
private final String[] whiteListSwagger = {
        "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui.html"
};

/**
 * Spring security filter chain security web filter chain.
 *
 * @param http the http
 * @return the security web filter chain
 */
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(whiteListOauth2).permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(whiteListSwagger).permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt();

    return http.build();
}
```

> Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6EKc.png)

*Tks.*

I tried to read the document but still not solved the problem.

[springdoc-openapi v1.6.12](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will help you:

https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1678

```
  @Bean
  MultipleOpenApiWebFluxResource multipleOpenApiResource(
      List<GroupedOpenApi> groupedOpenApis,
      ObjectFactory<OpenAPIService> defaultOpenAPIBuilder,
      AbstractRequestService requestBuilder,
      GenericResponseService responseBuilder,
      OperationService operationParser,
      SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties,
      SpringDocProviders springDocProviders) {
    return new MultipleOpenApiWebFluxResource(
        groupedOpenApis,
        defaultOpenAPIBuilder,
        requestBuilder,
        responseBuilder,
        operationParser,
        springDocConfigProperties,
        springDocProviders);
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).